Getting the embed URL of a Microsoft PowerPoint programmatically
Is there any way that I can get the embed url of a Microsoft presentation programmatically?
I want to use that URL and embed it to an I frame in my react application.
I tried using Graph API with the createLink API -

POST /drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/createLink

with the type as embed, but the url is different from what we get when we manually create embed url via microsoft web.
I tried to use that url by concatenating it with

https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=

But still it didn't work.
Let me know if this is possible or not. Thanks

I was able to get the url from the same Microsoft graph API

POST /me/drive/items/{itemId}/createLink

Once done I manually added some query parameters which remains same in all embed urls (em=2&wdAr=1.7777777777777777). Hence this url I was able to use in the iframe tag in react.
try {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/${fileId}/createLink`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ type: "embed" }),
    }
  );
  if (response.ok) {
    const result = response.json;
    const embed = result.link.webUrl + "?em=2&amp;wdAr=1.7777777777777777"; //got the correct embed url
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Error creating sharing link:", error);
}

