Update metadata of powerpoint file using microsoft graph API
Is it possible to update /add custom metadata of a powerpoint file using microsoft graph API?
I am using this API

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{file-id}/extensions
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
body: JSON.strigify({
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
  "extensionName": "customMetadata",
  "customProperty1": "Value1",
  "customProperty2": "Value2"
})


However I am getting this error

{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "[openExtension] The specified type named microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension is not recognized.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2024-11-22T11:58:03",
            "request-id": "7e156e41-f312-4221-9b5e-3235b9ecfce2",
            "client-request-id": "846b93a2-b2b5-00e4-57a9-6d97a77da548"
        }
    } }


Getting the same error in graph explorer as well. Scopes are User.ReadWrite.All ,User.ReadWrite

AFAIK, you can add custom metadata to user's resource like events, messages and contacts but not on drive items. Refer this MS Document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/opentypeextension-post-opentypeextension?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#create-an-extension-in-an-existing-resource-instance

Hi @akaparadox Any update?

Hi @Sridevi , yes you are correct, as of now we can't add metadata to custom files in Microsoft OneDrive

Also @Sridevi ,If possible can you also look at this query please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79189131/getting-the-embed-url-of-a-microsoft-powerpoint-programmatically
It's not related to graph APIs, but with respect to Microsoft PowerPoint Web.

Note that, creating open extensions and adding custom properties in it are supported by specific resources only. To know what resources support open extensions, you can refer this MS Document.
Initially, I too got same error when I tried to create open extension on user's drive item with below API call:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/itemId/extensions
{
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
  "extensionName": "customMetadata",
  "CustomProperty1": "Value1",
  "CustomProperty2": "Value2"
}

Response:

When I tried to create open extensions on supported resources like only user's /me endpoint, it worked as below:
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/extensions
{
  "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.openTypeExtension",
  "extensionName": "customMetadata",
  "CustomProperty1": "Value1",
  "CustomProperty2": "Value2"
}

Response:

For adding custom metadata to OneDrive items, there is one feature named custom facets which is currently in Preview state. For more details, you can refer this MS Document.

Hi, thanks for the explanation.
